# Getting List of Routes from RouteCollectionRoute

Tags: c#, linq, routes

I want to get all Routes from `RequestContext.RouteData.Routes` which is of type `System.Web.Mvc.Routing.RouteCollectionRoute`

When opening in Debugger I have the option "Results View" offering me a list of `System.Web.Routing.Route` which contains the Information I need.

How can I get this list (or an array) in code? I tried foreach and also looked if there are any LinQ-Methods that could help me (.ToList, etc) but with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such things as `Routes` in `RouteData`. [Proof](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routedata(v=vs.110).aspx)

`RouteData` only contains dictionary with URL parameters only. Probably this is not what you want.

But you could easily get all Routes this way:

```
var routeList = System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes.ToList();
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, this did not work for me, as I trying to acquire a URL manifest. Normally ApiExplorer would work fine for this, however we use a custom model binder and ApiExplorer does not appear to support that. More info here:

https://forums.asp.net/t/1835575.aspx?ApiExplorer+and+parameters+of+complex+type

Anyway, I was able to acquire a API URL manifest using this code:

```
    var httpConfiguration = Request.GetConfiguration(); //For reference

    var routes = httpConfiguration.Routes
            .Select(route => (IEnumerable)route)
            .Single(route => route!=null)
            .Cast<HttpRoute>();

    var manifest = routes
            .Select(route => route.RouteTemplate)
            .ToList();
```

Ugly, but it works, for better or worse.